# Materialized View With No Data still loading data

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb, continuous-aggregates

My understanding of creating a materialized view `WITH NO DATA` was that no records would be loaded until I or a policy I've set refresh the view. However, when using timescaledb and providing this option, I can immediately query against the table and it seems like records are being loaded.

I'm following these docs: https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/create-a-continuous-aggregate/#create-a-continuous-aggregate

`By default, views are automatically refreshed. You can adjust this by setting the WITH NO DATA option.`

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW timescaledb_view
WITH (timescaledb.continuous) AS
/* Query */
WITH NO DATA;
```

Yet when accessing `timescaledb_view` it seems completely refreshed, regardless of what query I've run. Am I misunderstanding how this is suppose to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume TimescaleDB 2.x as the question references latest docs.

The default behavior for a continuous aggregate is to use [real time aggregation feature](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/continuous-aggregates/real-time-aggregates/), which complements materialized data with the result of the view query run on the original hypertable. So in the case of empty continuous aggregate (as in the question) a select to the view will query the original hypertable.

The real time aggregation can be disabled by setting option `timescaledb.materialized_only` to `true` either during [creation](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/create_materialized_view/), e.g.,:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW timescaledb_view
WITH (timescaledb.continuous, timescaledb.materialized_only=true) AS
/* Query */
WITH NO DATA;
```

or by [altering the materialized view](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/alter_materialized_view/):

```sql
ALTER MATERIALIZED VIEW timescaledb_view SET (timescaledb.materialized_only = true);
```

Then if no materialized was done either manually or by a created policy, a select to the continuous aggregate should return an empty result.

Comment: Thank you so much,  `timescaledb.materialized_only=true` was what I was missing. Adding this to a table with millions of records and only wanted to refresh the most recent data.